# Angular Bootstrap Rating System

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a 21 point scale with the first rating being 100%, second 90%, third 80%....11th rating Neutral, 12th rating being 10%, 13th rating being 20% and so on up to 100%. While having these ratings display real time on scroll and selection. If you hover over the ratings you'll see the ratings I'm describing. Can't figure out the angularjs to get it to display..I'm also wanting to display the total number of Votes.  https://zepzia.github.io/angular-bootstrap-rating/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular Bootstrap Rating</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less">,
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl">
        <h4>Rating</h4>
        <span uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['100%','90%','80%','70%', '60%', '50%', '40%', '30%', '20%', '10%', 'Neutral', '10%', '20%', '30%', '40%', '50%', '60%', '70%', '80%', '90%', '100%']" state-on="'glyphicon-ok-sign'" state-off="'glyphicon-ok-circle'" aria-labelledby="custom-icons-1" style="font-size: 30px"></span>
        <span class="label" ng-class="{'label-warning': percent<30, 'label-info': percent>=30 && percent<70, 'label-success': percent>=70}" ng-show="overStar && !isReadonly">{{percent}}%</span>


    </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('RatingDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.rate = 7;
  $scope.max = 21;
  $scope.isReadonly = false;

  $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
  };

  $scope.ratingStates = [
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-ok-sign', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ok-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-star', stateOff: 'glyphicon-star-empty'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ban-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart'},
    {stateOff: 'glyphicon-off'}
  ];
});
```

Comment: What do u mean by screen reader?

Comment: @digit sorry screen reader was probably not the correct reference...I set titles for each check mark showing what I'm trying to display real time to the right..but you have to hover the check mark for a second for them to appear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working demo to display you title on real time scroll.

```js
var app = angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('RatingDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.titlesw= ['100%','90%','80%','70%', '60%', '50%', '40%', '30%', '20%', '10%', 'Neutral', '10%', '20%', '30%', '40%', '50%', '60%', '70%', '80%', '90%', '100%'];
  $scope.rate = 7;
  $scope.max = 21;
  $scope.overStar = $scope.rate+1;
  $scope.selectedTitle=$scope.titlesw[$scope.rate-1];
  
  $scope.neutralIndex= $scope.titlesw.indexOf('Neutral')+1;
  
  $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {  
    $scope.selectedTitle = $scope.titlesw[value-1];
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);   
  };

  $scope.ratingStates = [
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-ok-sign', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ok-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-star', stateOff: 'glyphicon-star-empty'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ban-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart'},
    {stateOff: 'glyphicon-off'}
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular Bootstrap Rating</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl">
        <h4>Rating</h4>
        <span uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="selectedTitle = titlesw[rate-1];overStar=rate+1" titles="titlesw" state-on="'glyphicon-ok-sign'" state-off="'glyphicon-ok-circle'" aria-labelledby="custom-icons-1" style="font-size: 30px"></span>      
        <span class="label" ng-class="{'label-info': overStar<neutralIndex, 'label-warning': overStar>=neutralIndex}" ng-show="overStar">Average:  {{selectedTitle}}</span>


    </div>
</div>
```

I hope I have correctly understand your problem and had resolved it.

Comment: What would the trick be to constantly display the percentage as the tallied average? Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: You need percentage also to display along with votes?

Comment: Was wanting the tallied percentage of all ratings to show always and when a user is selecting or hovering the ratings show the real time percentage of what they are hovering or selecting. Once they have made their selection the tallied percentage shows again.

Comment: I'm really trying to show the average {{selectedTitle}} rather than the average percent...and have it visible at all times.

Comment: https://zepzia.github.io/angular-bootstrap-rating/ - Updated github...if the tally is left of neutral it will always display the blue {{selectedTitle}} tally, neutral display yellow {{selectedTitle}}  tally, or right of neutral display {{selectedTitle}} tally. Along with the real-time hover selected title...

Comment: Updated solution Please check! :)

Comment: Hi I'm still seeing the percentage average rather than the selectedTitle average. Also, it's only showing the tallied average on hover rather than always visible

Comment: wanting it to display the tallied selectedTitle(s) similar to this when nothing is being hovered http://farm1.staticflickr.com/286/30832402833_0d2715f579_b.jpg

Comment: That's great that the vote is always visible. I was also wanting to see the tallied average of the votes always. While it shows what the user is voting I was wanting it to also display the selectedTitle for all of the votes averaged out.               Also what would be the ng-class for the neutral to be yellow. I was going for first 10 blue, neutral yellow, last ten red.  I updated the red and blue but not sure how to get neutral yellow label-warning: ?    You have been an unbelievable help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Having the first expression showing the average of all voters and the second expression showing what the user is voting. Currently seems to show the user only vote. Example: https://flic.kr/p/NYMNYD